# Using PAT or GitHub_Token to access a private GitHub repository with a subfolder

Tags: github, terraform, github-actions

I'm having a very difficult time finding the correct method to access a private repo in a github action workflow either using the GITHUB_TOKEN or a created PAT (GH_TOKEN) to use a repo with a sub folder containing modules.

The private repo with the modules has the path:

organization/terraform/modules/aks
organization/terraform/modules/acr
organization/terraform/modules/postgresql

My terraform main.tf is located in organization/terraform/main.tf

Here is a sample of the main.tf that references the modules:

```
module "setup_azure_kubernetes" {
    source                  = "https://${{secrets.GH_TOKEN}}:@github.com/organization/Terraform//Modules/AKS"
    cluster_name            = var.cluster_name
    enable_auto_scaling     = var.enable_auto_scaling
    resource_group_name     = var.resource_group_name
    resource_group_location = var.resource_group_location

module "setup_container_registry" {
    source                  = "github.com/organization/Terraform//Modules/ACR"
    acr_name                = var.acr_name
    resource_group_name     = var.resource_group_name

module "setup_db_postgresql" {
    source                        = "https://foo:{{secrets.GH_TOKEN}}@github.com/organization/Terraform.git//Modules/PostgreSQL"
    sql_name                      = var.sql_name
    server_version                = var.server_version
    resource_group_name           = var.resource_group_name
```

^^ Note that the first attempts to use a PAT token and the second doesn't. Both does not work.

Here is a sample of my yaml:

```
steps:
      - name: Checkout GitHub Actions
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: HashiCorp - Setup Terraform
        uses: hashicorp/setup-terraform@v1.2.1
        with:
          terraform_version: 1.0.9
          terraform_wrapper: false

      - name: Terraform Format
        id: fmt
        run: |
          terraform fmt -check
        working-directory: '.'
        
      - name: Terraform Init
        id: tf_init_dev
        run: |
          terraform init \
            -reconfigure \
            -backend-config="storage_account_name=${{env.storage_account_name}}" \
            -backend-config="container_name=${{env.container_name}}" \
            -backend-config="key=${{env.terraform_state_file_name}}" \
            -backend-config="access_key=${{env.storage_access_key}}"
        working-directory: '.'
```

Trying to search for information leads me to demonstrations for how to access a module stored in the root and not a subfolder.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I've tried all sorts of combinations without any luck. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I have done, I stored the token in the Github repository secret, use `Repository secrets` and not `Environment secrets`:

[image]

You can set env variable in GitHub action as below in any of the steps/run:

```
env:
  TF_VAR_github_token: ${{ secrets.TF_GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

Then it can be used as Terraform variable as needed:

```
github_token = var.github_token
```

Ref (how to use input env vars in terraform): https://www.terraform.io/language/values/variables#environment-variables

Comment: Thank you. Would you be able to comment about the sub directory and the path syntax?

Comment: Is this what you are looking? https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/references#filesystem-and-workspace-info.

In this example, I am using path.module to get the root of the Github repo:

https://github.com/tomarv2/terraform-aws-ecr/blob/f907471cecf3ae50d91662beabe60fea5f0e27ab/image.tf#L17

Comment: Hi Tomarv2, not quite, I'm trying to figure out what the proper syntax for a path as such would be: module "setup_azure_kubernetes" {
    source                  = "https://${{secrets.GH_TOKEN}}:@github.com/organization/Terraform//Modules/AKS"